# In Webpack, how do I set the public path dynamically?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am using `Angular2/Typescript/Webpack` to build an application

I'm having problem setting the Webpack option `publicPath` dynamically. In the official Webpack docs, it says:

> **Note**: In cases when the eventual publicPath of output files isn't known at compile time, it can be left blank and set dynamically at runtime in the entry point file. If you don't know the publicPath while compiling you can omit it and set `__webpack_public_path__` on your entry point.

**My question:** But how do I set this `__webpack_public_path__` variable and where?

I thought I would have to set it in `src/main.ts`, but then I just get compiler error `ERROR in ./src/main.ts`

```
Cannot find name '__webpack_public_path__' when I build the project:
```

Isn't `main.ts` where I should set this variable? I even tried to set it in the built version of the file, `main.js`, and that didn't work either. Here is part of my Webpack config where I set the entry point.

```js
config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
};
```

Comment: this helps https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/443 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> compiler error ERROR in ./src/main.ts

TypeScript compiler errors are mostly just really powerful *linting*. [More on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

That compiler errors just tells you the TypeScript doesn't know about `__webpack_public_path__`. Just create `globals.d.ts` with :

```
declare var  __webpack_public_path__:string;
```

And you should be golden. [More on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html)